# How would a zero gravity cat litter box work?

Tags: colonization, microgravity, animals

In fiction cats are often chosen as the optimal zero/micro gravity pet.  Clearly there is some rational for this, all existing answers at [How do astronauts turn in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2954/how-do-astronauts-turn-in-space) include cats in them.

While most litter boxes on Earth use sand or some pseudo dirt substance, it seems unlikely this would be a good solution without significant gravity.  It is possible to [teach a cat to use toilet](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/971/how-can-i-train-my-cat-to-use-the-toilet) so a space cat using a toilet is an option. Though it looks like current [space toilets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_toilet) use different facilities for liquids and solids so not the best option for a cat. How would a zero gravity cat toilet/litter box work?

While there have been a lot of animals in space they have all been confined, this question assumes a cat with free range of the environment like it's human companions.  This question is about the mechanical/physical solution not the training issues which would be best addressed at [Pets.SE](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10498/overcoming-challenges-in-teaching-a-cat-to-use-a-zero-gravity-toilet-litter-box)

Comment: Question is, how does the cat get into the litter box? Once in it, it would have to be a fully enclosed one anyway, so just throw in some of that silica based hygroscopic sand and let the cat do her stuff (what cat does in a box stays between the box, the cat and mr. Schrödinger). I'm not cleaning it after tho! :P

Comment: As an owner of cats, my immediate response is "awww hell no." Let's not take cats to space without a hab centrifuge.

Comment: Short of an extensive study done by a space agency (there isn't one), there is no honest way to answer this question without more details on what type of environment the cat would be in--which would be speculative at best since no existing space environment is currently configured to handle this.

Comment: I'm not the close vote though. I'd like to see this question work--please prove me wrong! I just don't think it is going to happen. We'll see what other users think.

Comment: @TildalWave why would it need to be fully enclosed?  In [this question](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1234/can-fish-really-live-in-microgravity-without-water) we addressed fish waste in air.  A content flow of air in one direction should in a box with one open side (entry/exit) should be a good start.

Comment: @JamesJenkins Do you know why the area surrounding the cat litter box stays clean here on Earth? It's not gravity, it's me developing OCD around it. :D

Comment: @TildalWave I think you are overly focused on using a substrate as part of the solution.  Did you visit the link on cats using a toilet?

Comment: @JamesJenkins Imagine a box with a sink large enough to take the cat's doo-doo, and air flow from above it going through it at big enough pressure so doo-doo et al. flow in that direction. Now guess where you'd find the cat next time she'd need to do her stuff. She'd be livid too! I think that if I'd want to solve this, I'd try to marry a Roomba with one of those [DoD SPHERES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPHERES) and bless it with some Robonaut logic (and an air freshener).

Comment: I, for one, offer blessings on your robotic marriage.

Comment: OK, here's an idea. Use a non-Newtonian [magnetorheological fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetorheological_fluid) over an electrostatic speaker, then control its viscosity, surface tension, shape and porosity with acoustic, electrostatic and magnetic forces provided by the speaker (its mesh will have to be modified somewhat to be also ferrous which they usually wouldn't be). You'll need some proximity sensors, constant supply of power, and quite a bit of fine tuning / calibration to make it work as it should, depending on how much of solids it holds _in the putty_.

Comment: @TildalWave you might be on to something. there are already earthly version of self cleaning litter boxes [random example](http://www.catgenie.com/tuxedo-package) you just need to have a way to keep the cat oriented correctly.

Comment: Random, but nonetheless interesting question.

Comment: The other question to ask is how would you ensure the cat wasn't stressed out in zero gravity. A few interesting videos of cats in zero gravity, one US, one Russian, the presumed US. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oW4Q1dKuR5w. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZVtpwRSyYSM. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JAWuMd6GOfs.

Comment: Maybe the cat can eat and drink stuff with  magnetic material in it. This creates an opportunity for a litterbox with a smell-o-meter activated huge electromagnet.

Comment: [SciFi solution](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104754/do-heinleins-novels-mention-a-plausible-zero-gravity-cat-litter-box/104927#104927) - I have encouraged the answer author to leverage on it for a solution here.

Answer (score 7):

How about a non-zero-gravity litter box?

While cats have a natural inclination towards the litterbox anything unconventional requires a certain amount of training and kittens require a certain amount of training anyway--you start out with the cat in a fairly small environment that includes the litter box, once it has a good understanding that that's where to go you expand it's environment.

That means you need a station large enough you can confine the cat in the area of it's litter box for a bit--that's a pretty substantial station.

Thus lets give the cat a litter box on a squirrel cage spun to perhaps .05g--we are simply after enough to keep things from floating away.  The "litter" is ferrous material encased in something that will keep it from rusting--magnets are used to keep the cat from tossing it out of the box with it's pawing.

The litter box actually comprises the whole ring although the cat only sees a small part of that, the rest of it is behind the scenes.  The cleaning mechanism normally rotates very slowly relative to the litter bed, it stops if it senses a cat in the box and then resumes when the cat has been gone for a minute.

Such a system would not work for small kittens and might be unsuitable for sufficiently elderly cats--it requires a cat capable of jumping into/out of the rotating ring.

Comment: The ring, or carousel, could have a single opening with a sensor that would start it turning when the cat entered so it would be stationary when not in use.

Comment: @JoeL. I considered that but I figured it might as well clean as much as possible.

Comment: I'm trying to imagine a cat jumping onto a spinning surface in zero g--doesn't sound easy.

Comment: If a cat is living in zero-g I would figure it has learned how to get around.  I think training in a spun section of the station would be needed--perhaps at first the cat is confined to the litter box ring.

Answer (score 6):

It's not an optimal solution, but fitted cat-diapers might suffice, at least for short periods.

Comment: So the astronauts would have to take turns changing them as their days routine. This might also prevent the cat from masking there territory (however it might be able to unlearn this).

Answer (score 5):

A solution by [Jack McDevitt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_McDevitt) in "The Cat's Pajamas" (2012)

> used magnetic gravel and gentle suction to overcome the problems of a zero-gee environment.

This was offered as [a solution to a related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104754/do-heinleins-novels-mention-a-plausible-zero-gravity-cat-litter-box/104927#104927) by Null On SciFi.SE